# C produces wrong results on 32 bit systems

Tags: c

The following code is supposed to take in a users input and write it into a file.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
FILE* fp;
char string[512]; //maximum it should ever be
char first[19];
char last[19];
char grade[4];
char choice[7];
if(argc == 2)
    fp = fopen (strcat(argv[1],".txt"), "wb+");

while(fgets(string, 512, stdin) != NULL) {
    sscanf(string, "%s", choice);
    if(strcmp(choice, "add") == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", string); //print out what string is
        if(sscanf(string, "%s %s %s %s", choice, first, last, grade) == 4) {
                    printf("%s\n", choice);
                    printf("%s\n", first);
                    printf("%s\n", last);
                    printf("%s\n", grade);
                    addData(first, last, grade, fp, 0);
        }
    }
```

As a test I enter in: add test tester 100

Add data should put the information into the file.

```
void addData(char first[], char last[], char grade[], FILE* fp) {
    rewind(fp);
    spaces(first, last, grade);
    fprintf(fp, first);
    fprintf(fp, last);
    fprintf(fp, grade);
}

void spaces(char first[], char last[], char grade[]) {
size_t i;
    for(i=strlen(first);i<20;i++)
        first[i] = ' ';
    for(i=strlen(last);i<20;i++)
        last[i] =  ' ';
    for(i=strlen(grade);i<=4;i++)
        grade[i] = ' ';
    grade[strlen(grade)-1] = '\0'; }
```

When added into the file I expect to see:

```
test                tester              100
```

Instead I get:

```
 est                dd test tester 1000                   est                dd test tester 100100                   est                dd test tester 100
```

On a 64 bit system of course I get this:

```
test                tester              100
```

What exactly is going on, why is it printing a bunch of information to my text file I didn't ask for? How would I potentially fix this so it works on 32 and 64 bit systems?

Comment: You're going to have a hard time shoving the string "100" into a `char grade[2]`, which has space for a one-char string plus terminator. Check **all** of your array limits. It would appear  that should be *at least* `char grade[4]`, and ideally you properly restrict input lengths on **all** of these.

Comment: You're right, I fixed the grade size and it started printing out the last name properly. I went back and realized I never accounted for the spaces in the sizes so it was going over and causing problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
fgets(string, 512, stdin) != NULL
```

What you have is array out of bound access as the array string can hold just 44 characters but you are allowing to write more than 44 characters.So the behavior is undefined.

```
fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin) != NULL
```

is what you should have

Comment: Be careful with sizeof. If `string` were passed in to the function, it would decay into a pointer and the result would be much different than you expect.

Comment: @Bill I am indeed aware of it being a pointer when passed to a function. But it is just a array here as I see it

Comment: @Gopi I think Bill means you will not know the size of the array when it gets represented as a pointer to the first item, so when you pass it to `sscanf` or to `printf` they can only rely on the terminating 0 (ASCII NUL) when looking for the end of a string. That's why using `sizeof` may be dangerous – if you fill the *whole array* with data, the string may get unterminated. Luckily `fgets()` guarantees to leave at least one char in the array and fill it with `'\0'`.

Comment: Besides the issues already pointed out, `sizeof` is **semantically** wrong. `fgets` wants the number of elements in the buffer, not its size in bytes. At the very least, do divide the result by the size of the first element (even if it is `1` in this particular case). Once the code is moved to use a Unicode implementation ([fgetws](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetws)), chances are, that you introduced a bug.

Answer (score 0):

As WhozCraig said, a bunch of my array sizes were wrong. I wasn't accounting for spaces when I set the sizes so the spaces were pushing it over the size I specified.